# How to create ssh tunnel and keep in running

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

I want to access machine A which is behind the firewall through a jump host from machine B.

I want to do the same either via ssh keys or via username and password.

What will be the steps and the commands to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called port forwarding:

```
 ssh -L localport:machine-a-address.domain:remote-port machine-b
```

Then you can simply use localpott on localhost to access the remote service on machine-a, for example:

```
telnet localhost localport
```